# How to bind current object to text input?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

## MessageModel

```
function MessageModel(content) {
    var self = this;
    self.content = content;
}
```

## RoomViewModel

```
self.currentMessage = ko.observable(new MessageModel(""));
self.addMessage = function () {
    self.messages.push(self.currentMessage());
    self.currentMessage(new MessageModel(""));
};
```

## View

```
<form data-bind="submit: addMessage">
    <input data-bind='value: currentMessage.content, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
    <button id="ButtonSendMessage" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

When user types in input box want the current message content property to update and when I click add I want the currentMessage to be added with content.  But the content is always blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because the *content* isn't an observable and the value bind is wrong beacuse `currentMessage` is an observable so to bind any property of you must to do like `currentMessage().prop` or use the `with: currentMessage` binding in an element context, try something like this:

```
function MessageModel(content) {
    var self = this;
    self.content = ko.observable(content);
}
```

And also i suggest you to use the `textInput` bind:

```
 <form data-bind="submit: addMessage">
    <input type="text" data-bind='textInput: currentMessage().content' />
    <button id="ButtonSendMessage" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

> ### textInput Binding:
>
> The **textInput** binding links a text box () or text area () with a viewmodel property, providing two-way updates between the viewmodel property and the element’s value. Unlike the value binding, textInput provides instant updates from the DOM for all types of user input, including autocomplete, drag-and-drop, and clipboard events.
>
> Ref:[TextInput Bind](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html)

Comment: Yes, this is the exact solution. Checkout fiddle which I don't want to be wasted: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/koLtcoqb/).

Comment: @NikolayErmakov So please set useful vote. But i see that you dont use the ````textInput```` binding, why?

Comment: Because this was not the key problem. But surely this is a good advice ))

Comment: well it doesn't have anything to do with the content not being observable, the fix was doing currentMessage() in the data-bind.

Comment: @O.O actually if it wasn't an observable the 2 way bind dont works